# Symfony2 with KnpGaufrette with S3 with LiipImagine

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, liipimaginebundle

I am trying to get LiipImagine running in my Symfony2 Project, using KnpGraufette Bundle to Acces my Amazon AWS S3 Account.

Now i can already access S3, store and load data and all.
I can use LiipImagine to filter local images.
So far so good.

Now i used the following config to glue together my gaufrette/s3 service and LiipImagine ans shown in this tutorial.

```
services:
  amazonS3:
    class: AmazonS3
    arguments:
      options:
        key: '%aws_key%'
        secret: '%aws_secret_key%'
        certificate_authority: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/cacert.pem'
  gaufrette.amazonS3_adapter:
    class: Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3
    arguments:
      service: '@amazonS3'
      bucket_name: '%aws_bucketname%'
  gaufrette.amazonS3.fileSystemService:
    class: Gaufrette\Filesystem
    arguments:
      adapter: '@gaufrette.amazonS3_adapter'
  our.fs.dataloader.s3:
    class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Data\Loader\FileSystemLoader
    arguments:
      - "@liip_imagine"
      - "@gaufrette.amazonS3.fileSystemService"
    tags:
      - { name: 'liip_imagine.data.loader', loader: 'gaufrette.amazonS3.fileSystemService' }

liip_imagine:
  filter_sets:
    s3_clientsbar:
      data_loader: 'our.fs.dataloader.s3'
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [50, 50], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
```

When using LiipImagine to filter a S3 recource, i get the following error:

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Data\Loader\FileSystemLoader::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in
```

The code for testing my filtering is this:

```
$imagemanagerResponse = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.controller')->filterAction($this->getRequest(),'the-actual-existing-loadable-aws-id' , 's3_clientsbar');
```

*Besides: Could some Moderator add the Tag Gaufrette, KnpGaufrette or KnpGaufretteBundle?*

Comment: Did you ever get this problem solved? How'd you do it?

Comment: No, and i do not have access to the project anymore :-/

Answer (score 3):

I think you does not have to define own gaufrette amazon s3 adaper service... just use gaufette bundle configuration.

Just use liip configuration like given https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/data-loader/stream.md

gaufrette + liip configuration then should look like:

```
services:
    amazonS3:
        class: AmazonS3
        arguments:
            options:
                key: '%aws_key%'
                secret: '%aws_secret_key%'
                certificate_authority: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/cacert.pem'

    liip_imagine.data.loader.stream.profile_photos:
        class: "%liip_imagine.data.loader.stream.class%"
        arguments:
            - "@liip_imagine"
            - 'gaufrette://amazon_fs/'
        tags:
            - { name: 'liip_imagine.data.loader', loader: 'stream.profile_photos' }

knp_gaufrette:
    stream_wrapper: ~
    adapters:
        local_adapter:         
            local:
                directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads
        amazon_s3_adapter:
            amazon_s3_id: amazonS3
            bucket_name: mybucketname
            options:
                create: true

    filesystems:               
        local_fs:
            adapter:    local_adapter
        amazon_fs:
            adapter: amazon_s3_adapter
```

Just notice that in example above I registered two adapters local and amazon s3.

Comment: `%liip_imagine.data.loader.stream.class%` is now `%liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.class%`